# Trouble understanding how to emulate String.substring method

Tags: java, arrays, exception, char, substring

I have to create a custom class, MyString, that emulates certain methods that the String class contains, basically acting like a string. The only thing is, I cannot use anything from the string class, only the constructor in one method.

The issue I am having is getting the substring method to work properly. I keep getting arrayoutofbound exception. I am also not sure how to compare two MyString objects.

```
  package hw;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyString {

    private final char[] chars;
    private final int index;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


    public MyString(char[] chars) {
        this.chars = chars;
        this.index = Array.getLength(chars);
    }


    //this is my trouble method
    public MyString substring(int begin, int end) throws Exception{
        char[] t = {};
        int n = 0;

        if(end > index){
            throw new Exception();
        }
        if(begin < 0){
            throw new Exception();
        }
        if(begin > end){
            throw new Exception();
        }

        for(int i=begin-1;i < end;i++){
            t[n] = this.chars[i];
            n++;
            System.out.print(t[n]);
        }
        System.out.println(t);
        MyString myTemp = new MyString(t);
        return myTemp;
    }


    //im not sure how to compare the two
    public boolean equals(MyString s){
        char [] tempA = this.chars;
        char [] tempB = s.chars;
        return true;
    }


    /*
    public static MyString valueOf(int i){
        Mystring string;
        return MyString;
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: Do you know what an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException means?

Comment: Please remove all code that is not required for solving your problem. This includes especially most other methods of your class besides `substring()`.

Comment: @TimoSta okay, removed a bunch of it, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

In the `substring` method `t` is created as an empty array of length 0 (`char[] t = {};`). Simply change this declaration to match the size of the resulting string `char[] t = new char[end - begin];` (if end is exclusive).